# Is there any way to retry only failed testng TEST in gitlab pipeline? My test run in testng and gradle

Tags: gradle, gitlab, testng

I am running my test in gitlab and when one test failed my pipeline get failed. Can I only run failed test not the job.
My project in testng and gradle.

I have utilized retry tag in yml file. Is there any way to retry testng-failed.xml file in gitlab